# CodeIgniter uploads directory

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

**I'm trying to achieve:**

I am using CodeIgniter.

I am trying to access `http://localhost/mywebsite/uploads/`. The directory exists, and via [a 3rd party upload script](http://www.atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/), I can successfully write to that directory. However, when going straight to the URL (or referencing its files in an src attribute), it gives me a 404 error.

**I thought the best way to do this was to:**

Make sure my `$config['base_url']` was set to `http://localhost/mywebsite/`.

(For an unknown reason, I can access `/mywebsite/js/` but not `/mywebsite/uploads/`.)

**I [read the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) and it said to:**

> Create a folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called
>   uploads and set its file permissions to 777.

That works to upload to, but it doesn't work to access from!

**I did it, I expected to see:**

Either a directory listing or permission denied page. I even tried going straight to a file, like `http://localhost/mywebsite/uploads/myfile.jpg`.

**Instead, I saw:**

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u set any rules in ur .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't know how I looked over the .htaccess file! I added "uploads" to this line: RewriteRule ^(css|js|ckeditor) - [L]. Thanks, that worked! (Do you want to post an answer I can accept? :)

Comment: haha, sure, i posted my answer. please accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your .htaccess file,
there shouldn't be any rule to restrict the access to the uploads folder.

("uploads" should not appear within this rule: RewriteRule ^(css|js|ckeditor) - [L])

Comment: Thanks, I had to omit /uploads from the RewriteRule :)