# Can't call php files inside uploads folder

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

This is weird, but I have a php file (let's say test.php)

If I upload it in the root or inside any folder (tmp/test.php, etc), I can access it via browser.

However, I want to put the file inside uploads folder. And when I put it inside uploads folder, when I access uploads/test.php, it goes to 404 page.

This only happens in production site. In localhost, it is fine.

Anyone had the same issue? I'm using CodeIgniter

My current htaccess is typical CodeIgniter

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe it's protected through `.htaccess`?

Comment: probably, but do you know which htaccess command that might protect the php? It's accessible in any other directories other than uploads though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049327/codeigniter-uploads-directory

Comment: If not in .htaccess, can also be in httpd.conf between <Directory /> tags. Otherwise it's file-level denial (ie chmod)

Comment: @CBroe The thing is other files other than php are accessible.